# Excel 2010 refresh advanced filter

Tags: microsoft-excel

I have a worksheet with jobs listed and specific staff members that are responsible for each.  I have created advanced filters to copy the job information to a separate tab set up for each staff member.   If I add a new job to the main tab how can I get it to update to the specific staff member tab.

Comment: How are your filters set up?

Answer (score 1):

In the Data tab of the ribbon there is a button to Reapply filters. Click that and it should do what you are looking for.